# Как заставить окно Screen Sharing не гаснуть во время простоя без фокуса на нём?

Tags: macos

Подключаюсь с мака к макминику через скрин-шаринг. Если убрать фокус с окна и подождать, то минут через 10-15 оно гаснет, но сам миник работает. Вернёшь фокус - окно снова загорается. Это как-то можно отключить? На самом минике нет монитора. Ось и там и там sierra 10.12.

Answer (score 0):

Отбой. Проблема решается штатными настройками питания на макминике. Просто оттягиваем ползунок выключения монитора до конца вправо, до состояния "Никогда".